# Module Params Custom Validation is possible?

Tags: module, module-params, validations

Now I have situations to validate Module params in admin side of a module.

I know there is option with [Filter](http://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type) in module params but its limited , I can't validate some patterns or custom conditions.

Is there any option available in Joomla to validate Module params on admin side ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom rule for validation. For example your module name is `mod_mymodule`:

- Add `addrulepath` attribute to the fieldset in the .xml file:

  ```
  addrulepath="modules/mod_mymodule"
  ```

This will be the path to the custom rule folder.

- Add `validate` attribute to the field with the name of the rule file:

  ```
  validate="testint"
  ```

This will give us the file `testint.php`.

- Create the rule file `testint.php` and put it to the path specified in the `addrulepath` attribute. So the full path will be:

  `administrator/modules/mod_mymodule/testint.php`

Here is a simple validation rule class:

```
class JFormRuleTestint extends JFormRule
{
    public function test(&$element, $value, $group = null, &$input = null, &$form = null)
    {
        return ((int)$value > 0 && (int)$value < 2);
    }
}
```

it should extend `JFormRule` class and you will need only one method, called `test`. `$value` will contain the input from the field. Here we are testing it to be integer between 0 and 2.

Comment: To get this to work, I had to change it to `addrulepath="administrator/modules/mod_mymodule"`, I had to add the line `use Joomla\Registry\Registry;` to the top of the PHP file, and I had to throw an error instead of returning false.